# Save multiple tables in mySQL using php (CodeIgniter) with multi deimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to save table data in MySql, where the first row of each table will be the heading of the table and other are there values screenshot for reference [image]

and my table structure as:

table for headings,

[image]

table for values,

[image]

there are multiple columns in each table, here what i tried:

```
    $col2=$this->input->post('col2');
      foreach($this->input->post('col1') as $key=>$val):
        echo $val."<br>";
        foreach($val as $key1=>$val1):
         echo $val[$key1]."__".$col2[$key1]."<br>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

i got column 1 value correctly but the other columns values not.

here is my fiddle for html structure and dynamic table https://jsfiddle.net/3yr1vuce/1/

Comment: Correct way would be use of column names instead that described row 1.

Comment: thanks @Tpojka for response, basically by using this query, `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2,...)
VALUES (Fruits, Vegitables,...)` or any other thing i can do please?

Comment: Your tables should be named `fruits`, `vegetables`. And rows should be as your rows [2-5]. Why would you save fruits/vegetables into rows? What is purpose of that? What is your goal?

Comment: there are multiple categories heading and there attributes is in there rows if you see my fiddle that will give you better understanding `https://jsfiddle.net/3yr1vuce/1/` when clcik on ad row a new row is added and add table for adding new table

Comment: Also see updated question for table structure screen shot

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here. At least to me.